# Cypress: intercept and modify part of the response

Tags: response, cypress, interceptor

Based on Cypress [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Intercepting-a-request), I want to modify a field on the response and leave everything else unchanged, after first loading the fixture. I know I could easily do this with 2 fixtures but I would not like to duplicate it for a simple field change. I tried variations of the following code but to no success. Any ideas?

```
  it('Should have the correct values in monthly', () => {
    cy.intercept('POST', `**/full`, (req) => {
      req.continue(res => {
        res.body.data.monthly = 5000;
        res.send(res);
      })
    });
    cy.fixture('calculator/monthlyRepayment.json').as('fixtures:monthlyRepayment');
    cy.route('POST', `**/full`, '@fixtures:monthlyRepayment').as(`request:fullData`);

    cy.get('[data-test="calculator:monthlyRepayment"]').should('contain', '$5000.00');
})
```

Comment: In your example, aren't you only stubbing one route? If so, can you modify your `@fixtures:monthlyRepayment` to return your desired `data.monthly` value?

Comment: Also, why are you using `cy.intercept` and `cy.route`? `cy.route` was [deprecated](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route) starting in Cypress@6.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I left a comment, but this will solve your problem, too. You'll want to [modify your fixture data before using it](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#Modifying-fixture-data-before-using-it):

```
it('Should have the correct values in monthly', () => {
    cy.fixture('calculator/monthlyRepayment.json').then((json) => {
        json.monthly = 5000;
        cy.intercept('POST', '**/full', json);

        // cy.visit called somewhere here
        cy.get('[data-test="calculator:monthlyRepayment"]').should('contain', '$5000.00');
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To do so I defined a reusable `interceptWithFixtureHook` command:

```js
export type FixtureHook<T> = (data: T) => T | void;

export function interceptWithFixtureHookFn<T>(
  url: RouteMatcher,
  fixturePath: string,
  fixtureHook: FixtureHook<T>
) {
  return cy.fixture<T>(fixturePath).then((fixtureData) => {
    const getData = (): T => {
      const data = structuredClone(fixtureData);
      const modifiedData = fixtureHook(data); // may mutate `data`
      return modifiedData ?? data;
    };
    return cy.intercept(url, (req) => {
      req.reply({ body: getData() });
    });
  });
}

Cypress.Commands.add('interceptWithFixtureHook', interceptWithFixtureHookFn);
```

Then you could modify your fixture base data or replace it, on the fly, in each test:

```js
type MyData = { monthly: number };
let monthly: number;

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.interceptWithFixtureHook<MyData>(
    { method: 'POST', url: `**/full` },
    'calculator/monthlyRepayment.json',
    (data) => {
      data.monthly = monthly; // here we mutates the fixture data, but we could also replace it
    }
  );
});

it('should do something', () => {
  monthly = 42;
  cy.get('[data-test="calculator:monthlyRepayment"]').should('contain', '$42.00');
});
it('should do something else', () => {
  monthly = 5000;
  cy.get('[data-test="calculator:monthlyRepayment"]').should('contain', '$5000.00');
});
```